Connection between dispersion relation and symmetries of the Hamiltonian
I am having trouble understanding intuitively the connection between the dispersion relation and the symmetries of the Hamiltonian. For example, suppose we have a lattice and there are four sub-symmetries of this lattice. What I mean by that is in an infinite lattice, suppose there are four axes where you can shift all the points and there will be no dynamics (i.e zero modes). Then one can approximate the leading order of the dispersion relation to be $$\omega(k) \sim k^4$$ I don't really understand where this comes from and why this is a reasonable approximation. I understand that the dispersion relation tells you how the frequency of a wave relates to the wavelength, but I am having trouble connecting this to the symmetries of the lattice.
From the above example, if you have a Hamiltonian on a lattice and you calculate the dispersion relation from that Hamiltonian and get $\omega(k) = 0$ for all $k$, does this mean that there are infinite sub-symmetries? As in an infinite way to shift points such that there are no dynamics?
Thank you for your time and I hope this question was clear. Please let me know if I need to provide additional information to help one answer :)
